# For an arbitrary $G(x,t)$, does $f_t=2G_xf+Gf_x$, $f(x,0)=0$ have a unique solution for $f$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, linear-pde

Let $f(x,t)$ and $G(x,t)$ be smooth functions from $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$.

The PDE 
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)=2f(x,t)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}G(x,t)+G(x,t)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)$$ applies on all of $\mathbb R^2$. Furhermore, let us impose the condition 
$$f(x,0)=0, \forall x\in \mathbb R$$

Is it necessarily true that $f(x,t)=0$ for all $(x,t)\in\mathbb R^2$?

---

EDIT: I asked this question on MathOverflow, and I got [a correct answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/275702/20838). It turns out it is not necessarily true that $f(x,t)=0$ for all $(x,t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Regards @DarrenOng . I would like to contribute. The PDE may be viewed as a 1D conservation law with a source function :
$$  f_{t} + F(x,t)_{x} = S(x,t)   $$ 
with
$$ F(x,t) = G(x,t)f(x,t), \:\:\: \text{and} \:\: S(x,t) = f(x,t) G_{x}(x,t)$$

$F$ here is the flux function, and $S$ is the source function. Now the conservation law (the PDE, which is in *local* form) is derived from the integral form (or can be called the *global* conservation law) :

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left( \int_{a}^{b} f(x,t) dx \right) = F(a,t) - F(b,t) + \int_{a}^{b} S(x,t) dx $$

Continuing this global form, we get :

\begin{align*} 
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \int_{a}^{b} f(x,t) dx \right) &= - \int_{a}^{b} F_{x}(x,t) dx + \int_{a}^{b} S(x,t) dx \\ &= - \int_{a}^{b} -(G(x,t)f(x,t))_{x} dx + \int_{a}^{b} f(x,t) G_{x} dx 
\end{align*}

The total value : $\int f(x,t) dx$ will change iff the right-hand side of the global form is **not** zero. Since $f(x,0) = 0$, we have
\begin{align*} 
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \int_{a}^{b} f(x,t) dx \right) |_{t=0}  &= 0 
\end{align*}

> Notice that 
>   \begin{align*}  \frac{d}{dt} \left(\int_{a}^{b} f(x,t) dx \right) &=  \left( \int_{a}^{b} f_{t}(x,t)dx\right) \end{align*}  so \begin{align*}  \frac{d}{dt} \left( \int_{a}^{b} f(x,t) dx \right) |_{t=0} &= 0 \\ \left( \int_{a}^{b} f_{t}(x,0)dx \right) &= 0 \\ f_{t}(x,0) &= 0 \end{align*}
>   The last one is obtained because the integral applies for *any value* of $a$ and $b$. Using this result, and write $f(x,t)$ as : 
>   $$ f(x, t) = f(x,0) + f_{t}(x,0) t +
>  \frac{f_{tt}(x,0) t^{2}}{2!} +.... $$
>   we get $ f(x,t) = 0 $, for any $t>0$.
>
> **Nonrigorous proof :** $f_{t}(x,0)=0$, $f(x,0)=0$, are enough to ensure that $f(x,t)=0$ for all $t$. This is because : if $f(x,0)=0$,
>   then $f_{x}(x,0)=0$ and $f_{t}(x,0) = 0$. Now since $f_{t}(x,0)$
>   (which means there is ***no change***), then what is the value of $f$
>   after $t=0$, say $f(x,0+\delta t)$? of course it will be the same as
>   before, $f(x,\delta t)=f(x,0)=0$ because there is no change. Now we
>   will have again $f_{t}(x,\delta t) = 2G_{x}f(x,\delta t) + f_{x}(x,\delta t) G = 0$, which means there is ***no change*** again.
>   This will continue to happen.
>
> This makes sense. But for me its difficult to show the rigorous
>   proof...

My conclusion is $f(x,t)=0$ for $t \ge 0 $. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Arief

But could you explain why $
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \int_{a}^{b} f(x,t) dx \right) |_{t=0}  = 0 
$ is enough? Just because the time derivative is zero at $t=0$ doesn't imply that $ \int_{a}^{b} f(x,t) dx \ =0$ for all $t$, right?

Comment: @DarrenOng I edited the answer. I presume that this is due to the cancellation in the source term : $  S = f(x,t) G_{x}  $ because $f(x,0)=0$. If the source does not have $f(x,t)$ as factor, then it is not necessarily that $f(x,t)= 0$. Since at first $f(x,0)=0$, then $f$ will increase or decrease only if there is a *source*. But the *source* depends on $f(x,t)$, so at each time the *source* will cancel out with 0.

Comment: thanks for the edits @Arief! The answer looks clearer now. But I think you are assuming that $f(x,t)$ is analytic in $t$, when it is actually just smooth in $t$ (for example, let's say $f(x,t)=\exp(-1/t^2)$), then $f$ is smooth but not analytic). If $f(x,t)$ is not analytic, it does not necessarily equal to its Taylor series, so I don't think we can conclude that $f(x,t)=0$ for any $t>0$.

Comment: @DarrenOng I added another explanation. But $f = exp(-1/t^{2})$ is not a solution, because $f(x,0)$ must be 0.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Arief!

I am afraid that the assertion  "$f_{t}(x,0)=0$, $f(x,0)=0$, are enough to ensure that $f(x,t)=0$ for all $t$" cannot be true.

Take for example the function $f$ defined by $f(x,t)=exp(-1/t^2)$ for $t\neq 0$, and $f(x,0)=0$. This function is smooth everywhere, including at $t=0$. However, note that even though $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t^n} f(x,0)=0$ for every positive integer $n$, it is still not true that $f(x,t)=0$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: Here are some proofs that the function $f$ above is indeed infinitely differentiable at 0: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491227/how-do-you-show-that-e-1-x2-is-differentiable-at-0