# Example on function g that is not even and where the derivative fulfill g^(2n-1)(0)=0

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, even-and-odd-functions

I am stuck in finding a function $g(x)$ that is not even, so $g(x)\neq g(-x)$, can be differentiated infinity many times and has
$$\frac{g^{(2n-1)}(0)}{(2n-1)!}=0.$$

I have tried with at lot of different combinations, fx. $\sin{(x)}+e^{-x}$, but can't seem to find any that fits the criteria. Shall I try to just guess more functions, and see whether one fits, or is there a system of a kind that I haven't seen?

Comment: $x \mapsto e^{-1/x^2}$ seems a likely candidate. See, for example, this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491227/how-do-you-show-that-e-1-x2-is-differentiable-at-0

Comment: @michaelhowes Perhaps with some modification (it is an even function after all!)

Comment: @Daniel Littlewood  My apologies. Not thinking cleary. I believe using the same function for positive $x$ but setting it equal to 0 for all $x\le 0$ should work.

Comment: @michaelhowes I agree, I think if you glue it to $-e^{-1/x^{2}}$ then that works too (choosing a smooth non-analytic function is definitely the important step).

Comment: It is really being creative, but I have tried with many different combinations, and it seems for me like that a function which has odd derivatives with 0 that gives 0, must be an even function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $g$ has the property that it is *analytic* - i.e. that it converges to its Taylor series at every point - then you will be out of luck. Since for a power series, $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{k}x^{k} \equiv \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{k}(-x)^{k} \iff \text{for all odd $k$, }c_{k}=0.$$
Sadly, most of the 'simple' functions are analytic, so it is not so easy to think of an example which will work.

The function $f(x) = e^{-1/x^{2}}$ with $f(0)=0$ is a famous example of a function which is smooth (differentiable $k$-times for all $k$), and is not analytic at $0$. It can be shown by induction that $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k$, so the Taylor series at $0$ is identically $0$, while $f$ is not zero in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Sadly $f$ happens to be an even function, but this is not an obstacle. The following functions 
$$g_{1}(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-1/x^{2}}& x > 0\\-e^{-1/x^{2}}&x <0\end{cases}$$
and

$$g_{2}(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-1/x^{2}}& x > 0\\0&x <0\end{cases}$$

(both with $g_{i}(0)=0$) both have $g_{i}^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for all $k$, while $g_{1}$ is an odd function and $g_{2}$ is neither even nor odd (the second example is due to michaelhowes in the comments). The proof is completely analogous to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491227/how-do-you-show-that-e-1-x2-is-differentiable-at-0), but feel free to comment if you get stuck.