# Maclaurin series of $e^{-x^{-n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series

The question states:
[image]

To get the Maclaurin series I was trying to find the sum notation of $e^{-x^{-2}}$. I know the sum form of $e^{x}$ and $e^{-x}$ however how do I convert $e^{-x^{n}}$ to the sum notation? I tried to use the exponent rule here (which I guess shouldn't be applied) as I got $e^{-x^{-2}} = e^{(-x) (-2)} = e^{2x}$ which is not true. Where did I make a mistake and how can I find the sum form for this exponential function?

Comment: $e^{-x^{-2}}$ does not have a Maclaurin series at $0$. The function is not even defined at $0$.

Comment: $e^{-x^{-2}} \neq (e^{-x})^{-2} =e^{2x}$, $e^{-x^{-2}} =e^{-1/x^2}$. You can define it to be $0$ at $x=0$ and look at derivatives of that function. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491227/how-do-you-show-that-e-1-x2-is-differentiable-at-0).