# Is a Set of Infinitely Differentiable Functions Linearly Independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the following vector space.

> $V = \{ f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} : \text{f = infinitely differentiable at all x,  } f^{(k)}(0) = 0 \;\;, \forall \;k \in (0 \cup \mathbb{N}) \}$

How would one show that this vector space is infinite dimensional?

---

To show that a vector space is infinite dimensional, one needs to show:

> Basis ($V$) contains an infinite number of linearly independent vectors.

I understand that if $f \in V$, then:

> 1. $f$ = infinitely differentiable
> 2. $f^{(k)}(0) = 0, \;\;\; (k = 0, 1, 2, ... n, ...) $

This would make $\{f^{(1)}, f^{(2)}, f^{(3)}, ... f^{(n)}... \}$ be an infinite subset of $V$, as each of the elements would also be infinitely differentiable and would pass through $(0,0)$.

But how would one show that $\{f, f^{(1)}, f^{(2)}, f^{(3)}, ... f^{(n)}... \}$ is linearly independent?

Comment: Hint: For any inifinitely differentiable function $f$, the function $x^{k+1}f(x)$ belongs to $V$.

Comment: @koala13 is the $k$ fixed or does it need to hold for all $k$ in natural numbers ?

Comment: @koala13 consider the functions $e^{\frac{-1}{x^{2n}}}$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Define these functions to be zero at zero. Try to prove that any finite set of these functions is linearly independent.

Comment: @KrDpk k is all natural numbers and zero - I will edit the question to make that fact clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Via derivatives:** Your approach works out. Let $f$ not be identically zero. Assume that some of $\{f^{(k)} \ : \ k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ are linearly dependent. Then we get that $f$ solves a linear ODE with constant coefficients. In fact, it solves an initial value problem of the form
$$\begin{cases}\sum_{j=0}^N a_j f^{(j)}(x)&=0, &&x\in \mathbb{R},\\ f^{(k)}(0)&=0, &&k\in \{0, \dots, N\}.
\end{cases}$$
Now, by Picard-Lindelöf, this admits a unique classical solution. However, $f=0$ is a solution, so we must have $f=0$, which yields the desired contradiction.

We are left to prove that there exists $f\in V$ which is not identically zero. Indeed, the function

$$ f(x) =\begin{cases}
e^{-1/x^2},& x\neq 0,\\
0,& x=0
\end{cases} $$
is in $V$ (see [How do you show that $e^{-1/x^2}$ is differentiable at $0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491227/how-do-you-show-that-e-1-x2-is-differentiable-at-0)).

**Via polynomials:** Alternatively one can use geetha290krm's hint. Namely, if we pick again $f\in V$ not identically zero, then we can consider $B=\{ x^k f \ : \ k\in \mathbb{N}\}$. One readily checks that $B\subseteq V$ (by the product rule). Furthermore, as $f$ is not identically zero and continuous, there exists an interval $(a,b)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ such that $f(x) >0$ for $x\in (a,b)$. Now pick $a_1, \dots, a_N \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^N a_k x^k f(x)= 0 $$
for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then we get for $x\in (a,b)$
$$ 0= \sum_{k=1}^N a_k x^k f(x)= f(x) \sum_{k=1}^N a_k x^k. $$
As $f(x)>0$ for $x\in (a,b)$, we get
$$ \sum_{k=1}^N a_k x^k =0 $$
for all $x\in (a,b)$. However, then we have a polynomial with infinitely many zeros and therefore, this must be the zero polynomial, i.e. $a_k=0$ for $k\in \{1, \dots, N\}$. Meaning that $B$ is linearly independent.

**Via cut-off:** For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ define
$$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0,& x\in [-n,n],\\ e^{-1/(x-n)^2},& x\in (n,\infty), \\ e^{-1/(x+n)^2},& x\in (-\infty, -n). \end{cases} $$
One checks that $f_n \in V$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Furthermore, one checks that for $m\geq n$ we have $f_n(m)=0$ and $f_n(x)>0$ for $x>n$. Assume that there exist $a_0, \dots, a_N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ \sum_{j=0}^N a_j f_j =0. $$
Then we get
$$ a_0 \underbrace{f_0(1)}_{>0} = a_0 f_0(1)+ \sum_{j=1}^N a_j \underbrace{f_j(1)}_{=0} =0 $$
and therefore $a_0=0$. Assume that $a_j=0$ for $j\in \{0, \dots, m\}$ for $m<N$, then we have
$$ a_{m+1} \underbrace{f_{m+1}(m+2)}_{>0} = \sum_{j=0}^m \underbrace{a_j}_{=0} f_j(m+2)+ a_{m+1} f_{m+1}(m+2)+ \sum_{j=m+2}^N a_j \underbrace{f_j(1)}_{=0} =0 $$
and therefore $a_{m+1}=0$. This yields that $a_j=0$ for all $j\in \{0, \dots, N \}$.

**Via bump-function:** Define
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
e^{-1/x^2} e^{-1/(1-x)^2},& x\in (0,1),\\
0,& x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus (0,1).
\end{cases} $$
One checks that $f\in V$ and $f(x)>0$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and zero otherwise. Now define $f_n(x) = f(x-n)$. Clearly, $f_n$ is smooth and $f_n(x)>0$ for $x\in (n,n+1)$ and zero otherwise, thus, $f_n\in V$. We have
$$ f_n(1/2+m)= \begin{cases} e^{-1/2},& n=m,\\ 0,& n\neq m. \end{cases} $$
Thus, if
$$ \sum_{j=0}^N a_j f_n =0 $$
then we get for $m\in \{0, \dots, N\}$
$$ a_m e^{-1/2} = \sum_{j=0}^N a_j f_j(1/2+m) = 0 $$
and therefore $a_m =0$.

Answer (score 1):

We prove that $\dim V = |\mathbb{R}|$.

The following is a set of functions in $V$ forming cardinality $|\mathbb{R}|$, and any finite subset is linearly independent.

$$S=\{ e^{-r/x^2} \ | \ r>1\}.$$

To show $S$ is linearly independent, it suffices to show that for any distinct $r_i>1$, $i=1,\ldots k$,
$$
e^{-r_1 t}, \ldots, e^{-r_k t}
$$
are linearly independent as functions of $t>0$. This is clear from Vandermonde determinant. Thus, $\dim V\geq |\mathbb{R}|$.

The reverse inequality is obvious from considering the cardinality of $V$ itself. $V$ is a subspace of the set of continuous functions, whose values can be determined from $\mathbb{Q}$.