# Cancelling maps whose derivative of all order are 0

Tags: real-analysis

$f$ a smooth real valued map on $\mathbb{R}$ whose derivatives of all order vanish at 0. What is kind of mild condition can we add so that this map is constant in a neighborhood of $0$ ?

Comment: "analytic" - but that's far from mild, of course :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Correct me if I'm wrong (I may be), but wouldn't that make $f$ identically zero?

Comment: @GPerez Yep, I admitted it's not mild :)

Comment: Have a look at this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240026/all-derivatives-zero-at-a-point-implies-constant-function