# $f^{(n)}(0) = g^{(n)}(0)$ implies $f(x) = g(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I want to solve following problem

> Let $f,g : (-1, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $C^{\infty}$ functions, and suppose that $f^{(n)}(0)= g^{(n)}(0) $ for $n=0,1,2,\cdots, $. Is there some $\delta>0$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in [-\delta, \delta]$?

Naively, from taylor series expansion of $C^{\infty}$ functions, I suspect that there is $\delta>0$ but I don't know how to prove this rigorously.

Comment: In other words, you are asking "Is every $C^\infty$ function also real analytic?"  As given in the answers, the answer is no.  You can find many more such questions if you use that rephrasing.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/240026/42969

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Take $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$, $g(x)=0$. Then for any $x>0$ $f(x)\ne g(x)$, but $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for any $n$.

Comment: Beat me to it. Perfect example +1

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

Here's a counterexample:

$f(x)=0$, the constant function equal to 0 everywhere, and let $g(0)=0$ and for $x\neq0,$

$$g(x)=e^{-\frac1{x^2}}.$$

Then, all derivatives of $g$ exist and equal $0$ at $x=0$, so the taylor series of $f$ and $g$ at $x=0$ are identical. However, clearly, $f(x)=g(x)$ only if $x=0$.